# How to parse JSON into different models based on key?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I need to parse JSON into different models based on one particular key that comes from server for example- if key = "userCoupon", I need to Map this into model called UserCouponDTO and if key = "discountCoupon", I need to map the response into another DTO called DiscountCouponDTO. I am using Alamofire for network call and ObjectMapper for mapping.

Comment: Ok so are you facing any issue? What have you tried? Any answer or tutorial you followed?

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4 it's very easy to map responses to swift structs using the new Decodable protocol

Have a look at this article: https://grokswift.com/json-swift-4/

An easy example where the server response matches the struct

```
struct User: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let email: String?
}
```

In this case the server might response with

```
{
  "name": "John"
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let user = try decoder.decode(dataFromServer, User.self)
```

in this case the User object will have name defined and email = nil

if you need to map from snake_case to camelCase you can use coding keys

```
struct User: Decodable {
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
  let email: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case email
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    email = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
    firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps